# How to receive invalid data from input fields in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

It seems that the ngModel does not return anything at all when it's invalid.

I want to play with the value when only 2 or three characters is inserted!

```
<input 
    type="tel" 
    class="fullinput" 
    ng-model="xxxxx"
    ng-minlength="12"
    ng-maxlength="15"
    required
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add name attribute to your form and to input. Then you'll be able to access needed value via:

in template `{{myForm.xxx.$viewValue}}`

in controller `$scope.myForm.xxx.$viewValue`

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input
        type="tel"
        class="fullinput"
        ng-model="xxxxx"
        name="xxx"
        ng-minlength="12"
        ng-maxlength="15"
        required
    />
</form>
```